'javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init()' Error on Tomcat for API Reference Server using Docker and Maven
I am setting up a reference server for the RESO webAPI so that I can build my frontend app. Here is the reference server...
RESOStandards/reso-web-api-reference-server
Disclosure. I have no previous experience working with Maven or Docker.
Here's the output from running build.sh...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  280.6kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ubuntu:20.10
 ---> e508bd6d694e
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e3a24b238f38
Step 3/4 : ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 53c8921f4549
Step 4/4 : CMD sh /usr/src/app/docker/scripts/build.sh
 ---> Running in b55854aa4487
Removing intermediate container b55854aa4487
 ---> 9f0e09535354
Successfully built 9f0e09535354
Successfully tagged reso-builder:latest

--2024-12-19 09:37:23--  https://github.com/RESOStandards/web-api-commander/releases/download/v1.2.2/web-api-commander.jar
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.116.3
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.116.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/241563456/46241924-dd2c-4d85-b293-3591cc391d2e?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=releaseassetproduction%2F20241219%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20241219T093723Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=ea9a6b19170744562e52e085a4e16e801e88b77787502a3ec233acce6ff271cf&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dweb-api-commander.jar&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2024-12-19 09:37:23--  https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/241563456/46241924-dd2c-4d85-b293-3591cc391d2e?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=releaseassetproduction%2F20241219%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20241219T093723Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=ea9a6b19170744562e52e085a4e16e801e88b77787502a3ec233acce6ff271cf&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dweb-api-commander.jar&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving objects.githubusercontent.com (objects.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, 185.199.110.133, ...
Connecting to objects.githubusercontent.com (objects.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.108.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 52741488 (50M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘temp/web-api-commander.jar’

temp/web-api-commander.jar               100%[=================================================================================>]  50.30M  32.1MB/s    in 1.6s

2024-12-19 09:37:25 (32.1 MB/s) - ‘temp/web-api-commander.jar’ saved [52741488/52741488]
    
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< org.reso:RESOservice >------------------------
[INFO] Building RESOservice 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ RESOservice ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/reso-web-api-reference-server-main/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ RESOservice ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ RESOservice ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/reso-web-api-reference-server-main/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ RESOservice ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ RESOservice ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.3.0:war (default-war) @ RESOservice ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [RESOservice] in [/opt/reso-web-api-reference-server-main/target/RESOservice-1.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/opt/reso-web-api-reference-server-main/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Building war: /opt/reso-web-api-reference-server-main/target/RESOservice-1.0.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.501 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-19T10:15:41Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

docker-mysql uses an image, skipping
Building odata-manager-app
Step 1/6 : FROM tomcat:9
 ---> 39642322f89a
Step 2/6 : ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="*:8000"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bbf4e98e530a
Step 3/6 : ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9bba1226eb2d
Step 4/6 : COPY ./target/RESOservice-1.0.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
 ---> 411fe5e0f1ce
Step 5/6 : COPY ./target/RESODataDictionary-1.7.metadata-report.json /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
 ---> e5357b015443
Step 6/6 : CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
 ---> Running in 37f23fca2a6a
Removing intermediate container 37f23fca2a6a
 ---> e625abeb4ce8
Successfully built e625abeb4ce8
Successfully tagged reso-web-api-reference-server-main_odata-manager-app:latest

and here is the output from the execution of run.sh ( which is just docker-compose up ) ...
Starting reso-web-api-reference-server-main_odata-manager-app_1 ... done
Starting docker-mysql                                           ... done
Attaching to reso-web-api-reference-server-main_odata-manager-app_1, docker-mysql
docker-mysql         | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.32-1.2.11-server
odata-manager-app_1  | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
docker-mysql         | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.32-1.2.11-server
odata-manager-app_1  | Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:12.401509Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:12.423930Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:12.426667Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:12.467456Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.98
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 5 2024 19:50:29 UTC
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.98.0
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.642 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.643 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.10.0-33-cloud-amd64
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.643 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/java/openjdk
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           21.0.5+11-LTS
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:13.688515Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.717 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.718 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.719 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:8000,server=y,suspend=n
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.720 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.721 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.3.1] using APR version [1.7.2].
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:13.817 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024]
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:14.335132Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:14.336436Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:14.436440Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
docker-mysql         | 2024-12-19T11:33:14.436534Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:15.082 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:15.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2756] milliseconds
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:15.322 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:15.323 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.98]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:15.360 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/RESOservice-1.0.war]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:17.611 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
odata-manager-app_1  | [main] INFO org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet - DB Type: mysql
odata-manager-app_1  | [main] INFO org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet - Connected to the database!
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:18.802 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/RESOservice-1.0.war] has finished in [3,441] ms
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:18.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/core.war]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:19.949 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
odata-manager-app_1  | [main] INFO org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet - DB Type: mysql
odata-manager-app_1  | [main] INFO org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet - Connected to the database!
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.454 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/core.war] has finished in [1,646] ms
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.459 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/classes]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.533 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/classes] has finished in [75] ms
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.534 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/generated-sources]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.561 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/generated-sources] has finished in [27] ms
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.563 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/maven-status]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/maven-status] has finished in [18] ms
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/maven-archiver]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/maven-archiver] has finished in [17] ms
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.608 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
odata-manager-app_1  | 19-Dec-2024 11:33:20.637 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [5444] milliseconds

Looks like it's up and running.
So I try curl http://localhost:8080/core/2.0.0/$metadata per the reference server repository setup instructions. The app reports a successful connection to the database...
odata-manager-app_1  | [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet - DB Type: mysql
odata-manager-app_1  | [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet - Connected to the database!

BUT the metadata endpoint request returns the following exception...
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [RESOservlet] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [RESOservlet] threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:396)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:937)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because "isCollection" is null
        org.reso.service.data.meta.builder.DefinitionBuilder.createResources(DefinitionBuilder.java:181)
        org.reso.service.data.meta.builder.DefinitionBuilder.readResources(DefinitionBuilder.java:325)
        org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet.init(RESOservlet.java:122)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:396)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:937)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.98

I've tried the solutions in this question How to fix 'javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init()' Error for Tomcat
It doesn't appear to be a dependency issue. Here is the output of mvn dependency:tree -DVerbose and none of my Maven dependencies use 'LATEST' as the version number.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< org.reso:RESOservice >------------------------
[INFO] Building RESOservice 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ RESOservice ---
[INFO] org.reso:RESOservice:war:1.0
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.23:runtime
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.11.4:runtime
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.5.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.olingo:odata-server-api:jar:4.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.55.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.olingo:odata-server-core:jar:4.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.olingo:odata-commons-api:jar:4.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.olingo:odata-commons-core:jar:4.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.0:test
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.688 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-19T12:08:07Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am going to continue looking for other related questions and I do need to try running OpenJDK 8 instead of 11. The server is supposed to be running OpenJDK 8 but I had issues installing that on Debian Buster so I used 11 instead. Perhaps that is the source of the issue.
Backend is my weakest area of experience so if you can see what I'm missing. I'd love to hear your thoughts.
UPDATE
Using OpenJDK 8 instead of 11 did not have any effect.

This is a problem completely specific to 'RESO', whatever it is. you need to read the source for the code indicated in:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because "isCollection" is null
org.reso.service.data.meta.builder.DefinitionBuilder.createResources(DefinitionBuilder.java:181)
org.reso.service.data.meta.builder.DefinitionBuilder.readResources(DefinitionBuilder.java:325)
org.reso.service.servlet.RESOservlet.init(RESOservlet.java:122)

You are likelier to get an answer by asking on Github.
